# Is the memory allocated inside a Java for loop released after the loop?

Tags: java, memory

```
for(int i = 0; i < len i++) {
    List<Integer> a =  new ArrayList<Integer>();
    a.add(1)
    a.add(2)
}
```

Someone told me that after this loop completes, the memory associated with `a` will be released. During the loop, is memory allocated for just one list or len*listmemory?

I mean how many bytes used during the memory, like 8*len or just say 8?

In my project, the list is very huge, so I am wondering, if I put the declaration outside the for loop, the usage of memory use is much smaller than this?

Comment: You should ask your `FileChannel` question separately. It is completely unrelated.

Comment: The memory might be released after the loop, or during the next loop iteration, or even never (if Java never needs the memory back). Garbage collection is unpredictable like that. But: * It will always be released if it's needed and nothing else is using it - your loop will never cause an OutOfMemoryError no matter how many times it runs. * It will never be released if there's any possibility you might use it later - you can never access released memory.

Comment: Thanks, how about the fileChannel, if I start a new filechannel in the loop, and do not close it, will it cause a out of memory?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be allocating `len` Lists. Generally, you put the declaration outside the loop. Also, you've dropped the type specifier (which is giving you a warning, and you shouldn't ignore those) -

```
List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>(); // Or ArrayList<Integer> in Java before 1.7

for(int i=0; i < len; i++) { // <-- Missing semi-colon after len.
  // List<Integer> a =  new ArrayList(); // <-- define outside the loop.
  a.add(1); // <-- Missing semi-colon.
}
```

Finally, the List `a` will be eligible for garbage collection when it's no longer reachable. In Java, you do not explicitly manage the memory.

(**edit**) It doesn't matter how many elements are in each `List` instance created in a loop or otherwise, when the reference is unreachable it becomes eligible for garbage collection. There is **no guarantee** of when (or even if) garbage collection will happen.

The memory usage is implementation dependent (but I believe the default `ArrayList` size is 10). And each Integer is a wrapper with a 4 byte integer and some overhead... maybe 40-bits? So, approximately `len * 10 * 4` bytes - of course a garbage collection could run at any point during the loop.

Comment: I mean how many bytes used during the memory, like 8*len or just say 8?

Comment: @user3495562 Edited. But you cannot explicitly manage memory in Java, so it is implementation dependent.

Comment: So if I put the declaration outside the loop, the usage of memory is much smaller. right?

Comment: @user3495562 I don't know what you're asking there... the List would have a usable reference after the loop (e.g. your List would have size `len` and contain the Integers `0` to `len-1`). What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I mean when the loop is running, is there a difference between memory usage in my current project, the list is very huge, so I care about the memory used is like one list or len*list?

Comment: I'd expect that it's more like `len * list`. You need to profile your code.